# How to convert a TextBox data to a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I inserted a `TextBox` in my `Userform`. The user is expected to input an equation of the format x +/- y in one of the textboxes on the userform. So I need the value of this equation in a formula. That is

```
Dim Y As Double, yn1 As Double, X As Double, D As Double
Dim N As Integer, E As String

Y = Yn.Value         ' value is from a textbox
X = Xn.Value         ' value is from a textbox 
D = StepSize.Value   ' value is from a textbox
N = NSteps.Value     ' value is from a textbox
E = Equation.value   ' This is also from a textbox. 
                     ' This is where the prob is because this is a text string    

For i = 1 To N
    yn1 = Y + (E) * D        ' E = X+Y
    X = X + D
    Y = yn1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 10, 4) = X
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 10, 5) = Y
   Next i
End Sub
```

This did not work because of `equation.value`. How do I go about it?
N.B: the values of X and Y are provided.

Comment: Evaluating arbitrary expressions given as string is not easy and requires writing a parser. If you want to keep it easy, replace the variables in your formula string with their values using `Replace`, then `Application.Evaluate` it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Range.Formula` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to set a formula. You can then use code like below to set the formula.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(i+10,6).Formula = "=1+4"
```

Comment: I'm using a textbox to get the data not from the sheet.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use Val() around your E variable to get the numerical value of the string.

Comment: Thanks. I did but it kept the value of Y to be 0 all through. Whereas only the 1st value of y=0. the others shudn't be.